# Is there a function to limit number of rows for pivoted data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to pivot dataset in python. Is there a functionality in pandas by which I can limit the number of rows based on pivoted column, after pivot is applied? For example, I have a dataset like this:

```
col1, col2, col3
A, 100, X
A, 200, Y
A, 300, Z
B, 500, X
B, 600, Y
B, 700, Z
```

After pivot is applied wrt col3, let's say dataset becomes like this:

```
col1,   col2
A       600
  col3, col2
  X     100
  Y     200
  Z     300

B       1800
  col3, col2
  X     500
  Y     600
  Z     700
```

Now, I want to limit col3 values per col1 value to, for example, 2 rows per col1, something like this:

```
col1,   col2
A       600
  col3, col2
  X     100
  Y     200

B       1800
  col3, col2
  X     500
  Y     600
```

Is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'pandas' won't do the layout I intend for you. This code will get you as far as you need to go.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='col2', index=['col1','col3'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
df3 = df2.groupby('col1')['col2'].sum().reset_index()

new_df = (pd.concat([df2, df3], keys=['col1','col2'], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
          .fillna('A').sort_values(['col1','col3'], ascending=[True, True]))
new_df = new_df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x[:-1])

new_df.set_index(['col1','col3'], drop=True)

        col2
col1 col3   
A   A   600
   X    100
   Y    200
B   A   1800
   X    500
   Y    600
```